# Using Option/Maybe to represent uninitialised variables that are initialised asynchronously

Tags: scala, asynchronous, option-type

There is a pattern in a codebase I'm working on where `var x: Option[A] = None` is used for variables which start uninitialised, and are populated at some point after the program starts, either with asynchronously loaded data, or in response to the very first event of some kind occurring.

After this point, the variable is always of type `Some` - the `None` part is only ever used at the start of the program.

Whilst this models what's going on quite well (the last event I saw is `None` when the program starts, and for ever after that it's `Some(event)`), I feel like I'm paying the price for using an option every time I interact with one of these variables, even though I only actually make use of it once.

It seems I was unclear - the value within `Some` can change, hence the var. I can't just use a future to await initialisation and go from there.

Is there a cleaner way to represent this delayed initialisation?

Comment: go with lazy val (which is more expensive than option, but easier to comprehend)

Comment: That doesn't capture the notion that this variable is None, for any number of queries to it, until it's no longer None, after which point it is always Some.

Comment: If you really want to see None for some time, then the Option (or perhaps [Future/Promise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html)) is the most cleaner approach. No magic pill there.

Comment: what comes to my mind is a stream. i dotn know your particular use case so its hard to be more specific.

Comment: It definitely sounds like you want futures, which won't get rid of the syntactic overhead, but will let you avoid `var` (assuming you don't need to reassign for some other reason), and will give you a richer sets of operations.

Comment: It sounds like a recipe for disaster to use `var` in multi-threaded code.  You are supposed to avoid `var` as much as possible in Scala, and to not use it at all in multi-threaded code.  Functional programming is becoming more popular for exactly that reason (easier to reason about multi-threaded code)!